# I have an image of a gradient which i want to copy into a shape i've created in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, gradient

I have an image of a gradient which i want to copy into a shape i've created in InDesign however when I click on the image, the gradient doesn't change in the colour box and so I'm unable to save that gradient and drag it into my shape. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you create the gradient in?

Comment: The gradient was originally created in illustrator, that object was then exported to a jpg or png which i have then dropped into my indesign file but when I click the new shape, then use the eyedropper tool on the gradient object, it doesn't change the new shape. I've checked that nothing is locked and that nothing is sitting over the top of the object etc.

Comment: Hi Katherine, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

InDesign doesn't always play nice with picking up gradients from other Adobe applications. If I were you I'd just select the shape you made in InDesign, and Place (<kbd>File > Place...</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the gradient's file into the shape. Some adjustments with the White Arrow tool should get you where you want to be.

Alternatively, you could try to make the gradient into a Swatch in Illustrator, save your swatches as `.ase` and import that `.ase` into InDesign. That seems a lot of work for just a single gradient, though.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I think I may have solved it. I've gone into my original Illustrator file and copied and pasted the object straight from there into my InDesign file. That seemed to pick up the gradient just fine although it's a shame you can't just copy a gradient straight from any image. Thanks for your help :-)